# tosca and git feature branching

Tags: c#, git, pull-request, feature-branch, tosca

For a customer I'm testing with Tosca. In the recent past I worked with Cucumber for Java and SpecFlow for C# to test automate my work.

For Cucumber and SpecFlow I'd like to work with feature branching (for each user story) and PR (Pull Requests) during a DevOps Sprint of 2-3 weeks.

Is this also possible for Tosca Commander? Or which actions (maybe refactoring Tosca itself) does it need to take to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tricky question!

As you know, Tosca is not an IDE and mostly used by testers without programming skills. While it comes with its built-in versioning, it does not support integration with code versioning tools (like git) per se. There are a couple of approaches to working with different versions of you artifacts (including working in component folders with copies of your test cases, exporting snapshots to check them in with your code, working with multiple projects, reverting back to certain revisions, a.s.o) but you won't get a git-like experience. Details about versioning in Tosca can be found in [the manual](https://support.tricentis.com/community/manuals_detail.do?lang=en&version=10.1.0&url=tchb/object_versioning.htm).

Additionally it might be a good idea to drop a line to the support to request the branching/merging feature. The more the merrier. :-)

Hope, this helps!

Michael